# How to place components in android?

Tags: android, xml

I'm now developing an android application . I place components in Nexus One . 
When I ran the application with nexus one or nexus S , it display fine . But when with 5.1 in WVGA or 4.7 WXGA both components and containers are no more on right location . I don't know what to do . Help me pls .

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/senka_background"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/senka_panel" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/txt_teamID"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
        android:text="  参加したいチｰムのIDを入カしてください"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_lsave"
        android:layout_width="263dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_teamID"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:background="@drawable/senka_button"
        android:text="チームに参加する"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:onClick="OnClickForSave" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_teamID"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btn_lsave"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:ems="6"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_lsave"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="チームID"
        android:textColor="#E3C545"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativelayoutRequest"
    android:layout_width="450dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/senka_panel" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/layout2textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="チームから参加要請があります。"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_otherActivity"
        android:layout_width="263dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:background="@drawable/senka_button"
        android:onClick="OnClickForSave"
        android:text="参加要請チーム一覧"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your layout file.

Comment: And what is the correct layout look like, and what is the problem layout look like?